# BeautifulSoup Web Scraping to find values of a specific key within the result set

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a webpage using beautiful soup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r= requests.get("https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1018849-classic-caprese-salad?action=click&module=Collection%20Page%20Recipe%20Card&region=46%20Ways%20to%20Do%20Justice%20to%20Summer%20Tomatoes&pgType=collection&rank=1")
c= r.content

soup= BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
result= soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})

print(type(result))
```

<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> , 1

```
print(len(result))
```

0

Here is what 'result' looks like:

[image: >>>print(result)]

I am unable to access recipeIngredient (highlighted in the image) as a dictionary keys. It gives me a keyerror.

```
print(result['recipeIngredient'])
```

KeyError: 'recipeIngredient'

How can I do this? I want to extract this from 'result':

"recipeIngredient":["1 pound fresh, best-quality mozzarella (preferably buffalo milk)","4 medium heirloom tomatoes","1 bunch fresh basil, leaves only, some reserved for garnish","Flaky sea salt, such as Maldon","Coarsely ground black pepper","High-quality extra-virgin olive oil"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to convert the data inside the script tag to json using `json.loads`. In order to get the data inside the script tag use `.get_text` method

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r= requests.get("https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1018849-classic-caprese-salad?action=click&module=Collection%20Page%20Recipe%20Card&region=46%20Ways%20to%20Do%20Justice%20to%20Summer%20Tomatoes&pgType=collection&rank=1")
c= r.content

soup= BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
result= soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
data = json.loads(result.get_text())

print(data["recipeIngredient"])
```

Output:

```
['1 pound fresh, best-quality mozzarella (preferably buffalo milk)', '4 medium heirloom tomatoes', '1 bunch fresh basil, leaves only, some reserved for garnish', 'Flaky sea salt, such as Maldon', 'Coarsely ground black pepper', 'High-quality extra-virgin olive oil']
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'd been at it for days.

Comment: Not working for this
URL:  https://www.booking.com/hotel/gb/thistletower.html?aid=304142;label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaBSIAQGYATG4ARfIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKIAgGoAgO4Aqe1040GwAIB0gIkMzY1MDE1NmItYjllNC00NGM0LWIwYWEtYTU4OTNkOGRmYzgw2AIF4AIB;sid=698c8213c64f03852f110753076ba0bf;dest_id=-2601889;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=13;hpos=13;no_rooms=1;req_adults=2;req_children=0;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1639287000;srpvid=52ad26abec37010d;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl

I need the value of this Key: "streetAddress"

output: St Katherines' W

Comment: I need the output: St Katherines' Way, Tower Hamlets, London, E1W 1LD, United Kingdom

But I can see this error: 

print(data["streetAddress"])

KeyError: 'streetAddress'

Answer (score 1):

That code is almost working, you are only missing converting it to a dict object, so it is easier to handle for you:

```
import requests

import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r= requests.get("https://cooking.nytimes.com/recipes/1018849-classic-caprese-salad?action=click&module=Collection%20Page%20Recipe%20Card&region=46%20Ways%20to%20Do%20Justice%20to%20Summer%20Tomatoes&pgType=collection&rank=1")
c= r.content

soup= BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
result= soup.find("script", {"type": "application/ld+json"})
data = json.loads(result.string)
receipt_ingredient = data["recipeIngredient"]
print(str(receipt_ingredient))
```

what i added here was the import json at the top and using it to convert the string to a dict object, so i can pull the right data.

Answer (score 0):

As you already printed, `result` is not a dictionary but a bs4 tag, to get the dictionary inside it use

```
result = result.contents[0]
```

Now you can index it with  `result["recipeIngredient"]`